# Can't open PDF: "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)"

Tags: upgrade, pdf, segmentation-fault

I'm new user in Linux system (I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS), and I'm learning english yet, sorry if i made a mistake

I'm having trouble opening PDF documents. when I try to open my default reader (Okular) it can no longer display some of the '.pdf' documents I used most ... recently I upgraded some packages, and after that no pdf reader works. I'm getting the same error warning on all the readers I have installed (Okular, Evince, Atril).

This is the error warning that I get in the terminal:

```
$ okular 

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.044: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.044: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.044: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:600:17: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.046: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.047: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.047: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:787:17: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.050: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.050: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.050: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1099:17: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.060: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2286:8: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.060: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2286:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.061: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2291:8: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.061: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2291:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.071: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4357:14: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.071: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4357:14: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4419:12: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4419:12: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4428:16: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4428:16: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4443:22: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4443:22: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4499:12: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4501:16: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.072: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4501:16: Expected a string.

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.073: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4549:12: not a number

(okular:8965): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:28:29.073: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4549:12: Expected a string.
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
   Segmentation Fault (core dumped) #(This part was in Portuguese, maybe in English it was different?)
```

Gtk-WARNINGS are common, and do not interfere with the usability of the program, but 'Segmentation fault (recorded core image)' is abnormal ..

Could you help me solve this problem?

the recently upgraded packages were:

```
2018-12-03 10:06:38 upgrade numix-icon-theme:all 0.3+933~201809192203~ubuntu18.04.1 0.3+934~201812011102~ubuntu18.04.1
2018-12-03 10:06:51 upgrade numix-icon-theme-square:all 18.10.03+201810041547~ubuntu18.04.1 18.12.01+201812011517~ubuntu18.04.1
2018-12-03 14:30:08 upgrade linux-generic:i386 4.15.0.39.41 4.15.0.42.44
2018-12-03 14:30:09 upgrade linux-image-generic:i386 4.15.0.39.41 4.15.0.42.44
2018-12-03 14:30:19 upgrade linux-headers-generic:i386 4.15.0.39.41 4.15.0.42.44
2018-12-03 14:30:20 upgrade linux-libc-dev:i386 4.15.0-39.42 4.15.0-42.45
2018-12-04 11:04:18 upgrade libperl5.26:i386 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.2 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
2018-12-04 11:04:20 upgrade perl:i386 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.2 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
2018-12-04 11:04:21 upgrade perl-base:i386 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.2 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
2018-12-04 11:04:23 upgrade perl-modules-5.26:all 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.2 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
2018-12-04 11:04:25 upgrade libfwupd2:i386 1.0.6-2 1.0.9-0ubuntu2
2018-12-04 11:04:26 upgrade fwupd:i386 1.0.6-2 1.0.9-0ubuntu2
2018-12-04 11:04:32 upgrade libpoppler-qt5-1:i386 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.2 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.4
2018-12-04 11:04:33 upgrade poppler-utils:i386 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.2 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.4
2018-12-04 11:04:34 upgrade libpoppler-glib8:i386 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.2 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.4
2018-12-04 11:04:35 upgrade libpoppler73:i386 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.2 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.4
2018-12-04 11:04:36 upgrade syncthing:i386 0.14.52 0.14.53
2018-12-04 22:52:41 upgrade chromium-browser-l10n:all 70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2018-12-04 22:52:43 upgrade chromium-browser:i386 70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2018-12-04 22:52:54 upgrade chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:i386 70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

I believe that perl, poppler and its libs were the packages that gave problem. I say this because was after these updates that I could no longer open the pdfs

I can still open some pdfs on my computer, but not all (unfortunately, I'm having this problem with my most important files)

thank you for your attention in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86799/discussion-on-question-by-evem-mc-cant-open-pdf-segmentation-fault-core-dump).